# KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, and Windows not being able to fix disk errors

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I've checked, and double checked, all my drivers are up to date. chkdsk told me nothing was wrong. My disk is 0% fragmented and is optimized weekly. Fast startup is off. However, when I ran sfc /scannow, I get this:

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For Example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

[Here's the log, it's very long and no pasting site supports a 3mb file so I just uploaded it to drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AnT3bsgEgAYD74KmkJg8PXnfdIWs0NlF):

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an Admin Command Prompt, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed again by SFC /SCANNOW.  See if SFC comes up clean this time (it often does the second time). If so, normal and nothing to worry about